# ios7 datepicker current date not highlighted

Tags: ios, ios7

What happened to the current date in the ios7 datepicker? In the previous version the current date was highlighted. In the latest version it can not be distinguished.

My datepicker is in "Date" mode. It shows "10 April 2014" for today. And the text color of today is the same as for all other days in the picker.

Comment: current date is highlighted in IOS7 also. What do you mean by "Not highlighted"? see Nicolos's Answer

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 7, the picker displays the date selected with a darker black font, and clears all other dates

so as you can see the currently selected date stands out very well , so your statement is not true

[image]

Comment: Sorry for being not specific enough in my question. My datepicker is in "Date" mode. It doesn´t show the time, it shows "10 April 2014" in the same color as the other dates in the picker. This was different in iOS6. Today had a bluish color and the other days a different one.